# Unable to create table in the database using Django oracle12c

Tags: django, python-3.x, oracle, django-models, oracle12c

I am working on a college project for which I am supposed to use oracle database as the backend and I have chosen to work with django as the programming language.
I have successfully connected django with oracle 12c and also have cx_Oracle installed. But when i try to run the command

```
py manage.py migrate
```

the following errors show up.

> Windows PowerShell    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> PS C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\onlinepharma> py manage.py migrate
>   Operations to perform:
>       Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, testing    Running migrations:    Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-
>   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py",
>   line 513, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params)) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an
>   existing object
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 353, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 83, in wrapped
>       res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 203, in handle
>       fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 117, in migrate
>       state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
>       state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 244, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
>   line 124, in apply
>       operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py",
>   line 91, in database_forwards
>       schema_editor.create_model(model)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 312, in create_model
>       self.execute(sql, params or None)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 133, in execute
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 100, in execute
>       return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 68, in execute
>       return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
>       return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 89, in **exit**
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 83, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py",
>   line 513, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params)) django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an
>   existing object

Here's my model.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class yoman(models.Model):
text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

But I have checked using sql command line and no such db table or view exists.

p.s: The makemigrations command works properly and the migratiosn file has also been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out the sql query if you edit the following file:
"C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py
On line 513, before the execute function is called add:

```
print(f'query')
```

Rerun the migration and you can see the sql that is failing to run. Either remove or rename the table/object in the db.